# Store with installments prices

Tags: php

i have this code to show 6 installments:

Parcele em até 6x sem juros.

I want it shows below:

Parcele em até 6x de 30 dollars.

In this case, 30 dollares is a exemples, its should divide the total price per 6 and show.

The code is:

```
    <?php
$vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');
echo '<p><small><b>Parcele em até '.$vezes.' X sem juros</b></small><br />';
for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
 echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
}
echo '</p>';
?>
```

It show the installments in lines, but is does not matter.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( $i=1; $i <= $vezes; $i++ ) {
 echo '<small>'.$i.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()/$i, true, false).'</small><br />';
}
```

This code above will going to run 30 times i.e echo list price 30 times.

what you can do is

```
`get list price`

`$installment = 6;`// can be changable

$final_installments = $list price /  $installment ;

for ( $i=0; $i <= $installment ; $i++ ) {
 echo final_installments.'<br />';
}
```